# Can we disallow the default alt text for images?

Tags: feature-request, images

Can we disallow use of the default "enter image description here" alt text for images?

I don't think it's too much to ask to describe the image you are embedding. I know that when adding an image it will make the alt text the selection, but I see too many images with the default alt text. I think disallowing the default alt text will remind users to describe their images (it can't get much worse than the default).

There are accessibility implications of poor alt text usage. [WCAG 2.0 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#text-equiv):

> **1.1.1** Non-text Content: All non-text content that is presented to the user has a text alternative that serves the equivalent purpose, except for the situations listed below. (Level A)

Comment: You might want to explain the importance of alt text; i.e. accessibility.  Otherwise, it's just "I don't liek it."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've added a bit. I'm not sure how much more I should add.

Comment: Related: 2,947 questions containing the placeholder [enter code here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22enter%20code%20here%22%20is%3aq) ...

Comment: Encourage? Yes. Use as a quality control factor? Yes. Outright disallow just because it has the default alt text? I'm not so sure. Can't editors help that out?

Comment: @StevenV Most editors won't see the alt text without viewing the raw Markdown.

Comment: Why is it important? What is the benefit of the feature?  Do you envision blind people get much information out of "screen capture" or "error message"?

Comment: @PM77-1 You sound rather harsh. I do think it is important. Maybe someone has images disabled? Maybe an image link dies and all that's left is its text description? It's more than just "blind people".

Comment: @PM77-1 And as I said, literally _anything_ is better than the default. Worst case scenario it's just as bad, best case scenario a careful questioner will remember to detail what is in the image (e.g. green bar with text above and below it).

Comment: Also related (and a personal pet peeve): 1239 [posts containing "enter link description here"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22enter+link+description+here%22).

Comment: This is covered by a law in USA, section 255 of the ADA (Americans with Disabilities Act).

Comment: "I don't think it's too much to ask to describe the image you are embedding." Oh you have **no idea**.

Comment: [Related, and interesting](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/things-learned-pretending-to-be-blind-for-a-week/)

Comment: My doubt is that then the most frequent image description will become "aaaaa"...

Comment: Good idea, OP. It would be interesting to see how many Stack Exchange users are sight impaired, and yes, alt text is a small thing that might make things easier for them.

Comment: @Bakuriu Worst case scenario, yes, the new default becomes "aaaaa", but that describes the image no better/worse than "enter image description here".

Comment: @BoltClock With the preview right below the textarea, I think the bar is low.

Comment: _[**Image alt attribute is certainly significant for SEO and usability.**](http://blog.woorank.com/2013/01/image-alt-text-relevant-for-seo-and-usability/)_ Just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: @halfer: [SO has millions of users](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com). There are [less than 2% people with visual disabilities](https://nfb.org/blindness-statistics). Therefore there could be thousands of users that might benefit from a text description directly. The meaningful description could also be useful indirectly if parsed by a bot (computer).

Comment: You'd never know how ALT text helps me to know that "there's a picture over here" if all images are blocked when I'm browsing SO somewhere (in my office). The worst thing I did was asking the OP where was the picture, when he replied it's over there, without ALT text.

Comment: The "average" SO question asker is unable to form basic sentences or explain their problems in an asnwerable way. They are unable to search or do basic debugging. How could you expect them to understand what an ALT text is and why it is important?

Comment: all xkcd comics except [this one](http://xkcd.com/404) use alt text for describing the images.

Answer (score 73):

Accessibility is a major issue, but it is not that simple to ensure users are entering meaningful `alt` text. I would prefer that it is explained why it is important, but not required, to avoid users entering "aaaaaaa". If the user leaves the default, it should be filtered out and no `alt` should be displayed.

Based on the WHATWG Living HTML standard, in general, images should have `alt` information if they are not fully described by the text around them. If they are described in the text around them, the `alt` should be `alt=""` to indicate that the image is already described. **If the user simply does not provide alt text, the `alt` element should be omitted, to indicate that the significance of the image is unknown.** See more in my answer to [When is it acceptable to leave the alt text empty on an HTML image (if ever)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526791/when-is-it-acceptable-to-leave-the-alt-text-empty-on-an-html-image-if-ever/23526792#23526792).

Comment: +1 This is extremely reasonable and your linked answer is a good read. (Where the OP is a "feature-request", I don't know if I should _accept_ this.)

Comment: +1 I confess to often not providing alt text. However, I mostly embed images in questions about plotting where the image shows the resulting plot. I'm unsure how visually impaired people could profit from those questions at all, but if they do they don't really need the resulting plots (and those could often be produced with the code I provide). So, just omiting alt text seems like a good solution.

Comment: The more practical reason for using 'alt=""' is that many screen readers will read any non-empty alt text. Having "enter image description here" read out loud to you a few dozen times a days must be rather annoying.

Comment: @Roland: Imagine you are blind and you want to find something on your table. Wouldn’t it be nice if every single thing said what it is when you touch it, saving you time needed to find out that you want some other thing? “Plot generated by the code above” could be a reasonable description of your images. *I’m not an expert on accessibility, maybe there is a better alternative text.*

Comment: @Whymarrh The asker is always in full control of how, when and whether to accept an answer. Feel free to accept an answer to a `[feature-request]`, with the knowledge that your green check mark will not significantly influence how, when and whether such feature is implemented.

Comment: Omitting the alt tag is against HTML5 working draft specification, making it invalid HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#alt

Comment: @Spork: That's W3C HTML5 for you. The question therefore is not whether it's valid, but whose side you're on - the more lenient but less predictable WHATWG, or the stricter but more straightforward W3C.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar idea. Use the new-ish "[Review your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399374/6083675)" step to alert to possible accessibility problems, such as bad alt text. Many people just need instruction and will be able to create ok alt text.

However, I wouldn't block posting entirely. That will cause many users to just delete all the placeholder text (even when that's inappropriate) or replace it with "screenshot" or "code" (yes, it certainly will be code too).

It's easier to find posts that need attention (so you can create a proper alt text) when you can search for the default alt text (probably only possible through data explorer).

Answer (score -4):

How hard would it be when adding images to tell between the "random" file names that sites like Imgur use for files people have uploaded to them and ones with "real" names either uploaded from the users PC or from a website that doesn't do automatic renaming on upload?  If this could be done, the filename could be used as a better alt-text than the current default.

Comment: I usually just paste a screenshot right from my clipboard onto imgur. Even in the unlikely case that someone took the time to save it to their HDD, it is unlikely that they named it "Text_where_top_right_corner_is_red.png". "Screeny3.png" or "redcorner.png" are just as useless as no description at all. Worst of all, you would make people believe that is actually a valid alt text, if they even realize it becomes alt text at all...

Comment: @Sumurai8 ... actually, that *is* what I normally do do, shortly before swearing because I forgot that SO will "helpfully" rename the file with imgur's standard gibberish again.  I haven't took any stats, but a non-trivial number of the screenshots as links I see in the first post queue were done the same way.

Comment: I find you a special person, as I don't know many people who will assign a very descriptive name to a file that they need at most once. I'll give you this virtual free cookie for that, even though I still disagree that it is a bad idea to do this.

Comment: I use meaningful names on my screen shots. And I usually retype the name after posting to SE into the alt text. +1 I'm totally in favor of defaulting to the original filename.