# Step 2 Question review redundant suggestions

Tags: bug, ask-question-form

"Step 2: Review your question" advises me to add a tag for the application I'm developing on, specifically suggesting [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) even though it has already been added to my question.

It seems like this is specific to the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag because although it's not the first time it's happened, it's always the same tag.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These tips are "dumb", in the way that they're not interactive at all. They suggest this improvement as soon as you add the tag that carries the tip, irregardless of if you already added the tag.

Both the ones for SQL and for VBA nag you about adding related tags even if you've already added them. This is by design, and not specific to the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag, or even the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag since [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) has a similar message.

You could add a feature request to make this interactive and hide the tip if it's been acted upon, but I personally don't think SE is willing to invest dev time on this.

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like the OP is adding the [access-vba] tag... Isn't that getting burninated? (Just trying to save you a question's worth of work ;))

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's getting merged with [tag:vba] (at least I hope, I've invested some work to make sure all questions tagged [tag:access-vba] are also tagged [tag:ms-access]), so as long as it's accompanied with the [tag:ms-access] tag I don't mind. A certain user does mind, though, and will edit them out as soon as they're posted.